# SQL Server table first name last name

Tags: sql

I have two tables

```
select * from elig
select * from elig1
```

in the same database.

Table 1

```
Firstname, Lastname, MemberNo
```

Table 2

```
Firstname, Lastname, MemeberNo
```

Table 1:

```
ash                  dassant              1
alex                 peters               2
john                 lex                  3
kyle                 passant              4
file                 leters               5
zed                  luthr                6
```

Table 2:

```
a                    dassant              1
a                    peters               2
j                    lex                  3
```

When I try to select the records from table 1 I get complete firstname and lastname

But when I try to select records from table 2 I get only the first letter of first name and complete lastname

Any help here would be appreciated if I can get the full first name for second table

Comment: Show sample data, your current query that has the issue, and tag the database you are using (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc)

Comment: Which attempts have you tried so far? Can you post your code? Can you post your input and desired output?

Comment: ash                  dassant              1
alex                 peters                 2
john                 lex                      3
kyle                 passant              4
file                  leters                   5
zed                  luthr                  6

Comment: If all you are doing is `SELECT * FROM table2` then you only have the first letter of the firstname stored in table2.  Possibly the column is a string datatype with a length of 1 and truncated your data on insert, although that usually throws an error.

Comment: It appears the reason you are only getting the first letter of the first name in table 2 is that is how the data is set up.    Does the 3rd column represent a primary key for these people? If so, you can join your tables on the primary key assuming that the ID # from table 1 = ID # from table 2. Are the names of your tables "Table 1" & "Table 2" ?

Comment: Do all of the records in table 2 already exist in table 1? If so, using table 2 would be redundant.